# Retrieve unselected option in a select list using Flask

Tags: python, post, flask, selectlist, multiple-select

What's up guy?

I'm working on a Flask project using a multiple select form see: http://jsfiddle.net/nzdak7aL/1/ for an example of.

I want to submit all items inside the boxes to a flask back-end environment via POST method.
If I select all items in all boxes before clicking the submit button I can get the data using `request.form` (and its variation) on flask.

[image]

This I get only the items `Nick Fury` and `The Hulk` but not `Iron Man`.

So I can't get the items if I do not select them.

[image]

It doesn't return anything, but I need the items in this box.

I already tried set the name as a list `name="boxName[]"` but it didn't work. Returns always `None` or `[]`.

Comment: you should have list with all items in Flask (back-end) and remove items which you get from `form` to get elements which were not selected. OR you will have to use JavaScript to reverse selection before send to Flask (back-end) when you click submit,.

Comment: I couldn't get by python I had to go to JavaScript as you said and send the data using fetch request. Thanks man!